# while deploying my react app on vercel i am having this error "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.json»plugin:react/recommended" and BaseConfig

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, vercel

I am trying to deploy my react js application on vercel and i am having this error:

```
[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.json » plugin:react/recommended" and "BaseConfig » /vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js".
```

This is the complete log:

```
[21:44:55.025] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[21:44:55.073] Cloning github.com/SarfarazAhmed1012/insta-pay (Branch: main, Commit: 44ec3c0)
[21:44:55.373] Previous build cache not available
[21:44:56.219] Cloning completed: 1.146s
[21:44:56.525] Running "vercel build"
[21:44:57.106] Vercel CLI 28.18.1
[21:44:57.958] Warning: Due to "engines": { "node": "14 || 15 || 16" } in your `package.json` file, the Node.js Version defined in your Project Settings ("18.x") will not apply. Learn More: http://vercel.link/node-version
[21:44:57.963] Installing dependencies...
[21:44:58.347] yarn install v1.22.17
[21:44:58.402] info No lockfile found.
[21:44:58.412] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[21:44:58.417] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[21:45:02.135] warning @testing-library/jest-dom > css > source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[21:45:07.583] warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
[21:45:08.586] warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
[21:45:08.743] warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
[21:45:08.905] warning react-scripts > css-minimizer-webpack-plugin > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
[21:45:09.548] warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @rollup/plugin-replace > magic-string > sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
[21:45:09.611] warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
[21:45:10.191] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[21:45:51.009] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[21:45:51.012] warning " > @asseinfo/react-kanban@2.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
[21:45:51.012] warning " > @asseinfo/react-kanban@2.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
[21:45:51.016] warning " > @testing-library/user-event@14.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
[21:45:51.017] warning " > react-chartjs-2@3.0.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
[21:45:51.017] warning " > react-images-viewer@1.7.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.0 || ^16.0 || ^17.0".
[21:45:51.018] warning " > react-images-viewer@1.7.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.0 || ^16.0 || ^17.0".
[21:45:51.018] warning "react-leaflet > @react-leaflet/core@2.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "leaflet@^1.9.0".
[21:45:51.019] warning " > react-quill@1.3.5" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0".
[21:45:51.023] warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
[21:45:51.023] warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
[21:45:51.025] warning "react-scripts > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
[21:45:51.034] warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[21:46:22.742] [5/5] Building fresh packages...
[21:46:24.148] success Saved lockfile.
[21:46:24.155] Done in 85.81s.
[21:46:24.236] Running "yarn run build"
[21:46:24.464] yarn run v1.22.17
[21:46:24.525] $ react-scripts build
[21:46:26.155] Creating an optimized production build...
[21:46:48.922] [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /vercel/path0/src/assets/images/illustrations/404.svg as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[21:46:50.765] [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of undefined as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[21:48:17.820] Failed to compile.
[21:48:17.820] 
[21:48:17.821] [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.json » plugin:react/recommended" and "BaseConfig » /vercel/path0/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js".
[21:48:17.821] 
[21:48:17.821] 
[21:48:17.871] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[21:48:17.871] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[21:48:17.892] Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
[21:48:18.196] BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

this is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "argon-dashboard-pro-mui",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "author": "Creative Tim",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <https://www.creative-tim.com/license>",
  "description": "my dashboard",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-argon-dashboard-pro-material-ui/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-argon-dashboard-pro-material-ui.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14 || 15 || 16",
    "npm": ">=6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@asseinfo/react-kanban": "2.2.0",
    "@emotion/cache": "11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.8.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "5.11.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.8.2",
    "@mui/material": "5.8.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "5.8.0",
    "@pathofdev/react-tag-input": "1.0.7",
    "@react-leaflet/core": "2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.2.0",
    "chart.js": "3.4.1",
    "chroma-js": "2.4.2",
    "dropzone": "5.9.3",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.13",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "html-react-parser": "1.4.14",
    "leaflet": "1.8.0",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "3.0.4",
    "react-circular-slider-svg": "0.1.5",
    "react-countup": "6.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-flatpickr": "3.10.12",
    "react-github-btn": "1.3.0",
    "react-images-viewer": "1.7.1",
    "react-leaflet": "4.0.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.8",
    "react-quill": "1.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "5.3.2",
    "react-table": "7.8.0",
    "stylis": "4.1.1",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "2.1.1",
    "sweetalert2": "11.4.17",
    "swiper": "^6.0.2",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4",
    "yup": "0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "install:peer-deps": "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

and below is my **eslintrc.json** file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "import", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "react/require-default-props": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/alt-text": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/display-name": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/resolver": { "node": { "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"] } }
  },
  "globals": {
    "JSX": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the conflicting rule in **.eslintrc.json**

```
"rules": {
  "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
}
```